# How to convert xml files to groovy syntax from command line

Tags: xml, groovy

is there any way to convert xml file to groovy syntax to be used in Xml MarkupBuilder?
For example: the foo.xml file look like:

```
<foo attribute1="value1" attribute2="value2">
    <nestedFoo>
       sampleText
    </nestedFoo>
</foo>
```

Then execute the the command line that I'm looking for:

```
<command line> foo.xml foo.groovy
```

the foo.groovy will look something like this:

```
foo(attribute1:'value1', attribute2:'value2') {
   nestedFoo('sampleTest')
}
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: You want to convert from xml to a groovy script that would generate the xml when run?

Answer (score 4):

I came up with this:

Given some example XML:

```
def xml = """<foo attribute1="value1" attribute2="value2">
    <nestedFoo>
       sampleText
    </nestedFoo>
</foo>"""
```

We can then parse it in using `XmlParser`, and work through the nodes, writing data to a writer

```
def s = new XmlParser().parseText( xml )

// Closure for writing the xml to a writer as Groovy
// builder style code
def dumpNode
dumpNode = { node, writer, indent = '    ' ->
  // Contents of the node, followed by the attributes
  def attrs = node.text()?.trim()
  attrs = attrs ? [ "'$attrs'" ] : []
  attrs = node.attributes().inject( attrs ) { a, v ->
    a << "$v.key:'$v.value'"
  }.join( ', ' )

  // write out the method definition
  writer << "${indent}${node.name()}( $attrs )"

  writer << ' {\n'
  node.children().each {
    if( it instanceof Node ) dumpNode( it, writer, "  $indent" )
  }
  writer << "$indent}\n"
}

def sw = new StringWriter()

sw << 'println new StringWriter().with { out ->\n'
sw << '  new groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder( out ).with { smb ->\n'

dumpNode( s, sw )

sw << '  }\n'
sw << '  out.toString()\n'
sw << '}\n'

println sw
```

Running this code, prints out:

```
println new StringWriter().with { out ->
  new groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder( out ).with { smb ->
    foo( attribute1:'value1', attribute2:'value2' ) {
      nestedFoo( 'sampleText' ) {
      }
    }
  }
  out.toString()
}
```

Then, if you run that in Groovy, you get:

```
<foo attribute1='value1' attribute2='value2'>
  <nestedFoo>sampleText</nestedFoo>
</foo>
```